# gcloud compute instance create failed - required 'compute.subnetworks.use' permission

Tags: permissions, google-compute-engine

Gcloud returned the following error when attempting to create the instance on GCE. The command was initiated from a GCE instance with the scope set to 'Full API access to all Google cloud services' and has project-wide SSH keys blocked.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Some requests did not succeed: 
- Required 'compute.subnetworks.use' permission for 'projects/[project-name]/regions/[region]/subnetworks/default'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I couldn't find any resource anywhere on that error.

Comment: Is this still happening? If so, make sure that you have the latest gcloud version.  Additionally run ¨gcloud auth list¨ and ¨gcloud config list¨ to verify the credentials that gcloud SDK is using. A good test to troubleshoot is deploying different resources in different zones and regions.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? If so please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Carlos has good suggestion in the comment. Posting them as an answer for other user's looking for help:

- Make sure you have the latest gcloud version installed. You can run **gcloud version** to see the version and **gcloud components update** to update.
- You can run **gcloud auth list** and **gcloud config list** to verify gcloud is authenticated with the correct user/service account.
- To debug further you can deploy the instance in different network and zone.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add permissions to the project that network is in, so

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding YOUR_NETWORK_PROJECT_ID_HERE --role roles/compute.networkUser     --member serviceAccount:YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE
```